# About list of installed app details in iOS

Tags: objective-c

i found one android application that display the list of all installed applications and on selecting a particular application it will display the name and email id of the app developer/publisher and app version etc...

so my question is - Can we implement the same concept in non-jailbreak iOS device?

thanks for reply in advance
danish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible in non jailbreak device. In Ios apps in sandbox so you not get information of other apps in device.  you can check some apps are install in device by open url schema but not get all apps..

Answer (score 0):

No, the best you can do is go over the [list of app launch URLs](http://handleopenurl.com) and see if there's a responsible app, but this only covers a tiny bit of app store.